# Amazon Mobile In App purchase requires my own server?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, application-server, amazon-appstore

looking at this diagram suggests that in app purchasing requires that I have an application server.

[image]

I don't have an application server for this project, can I use Amazon In App purchases? Mainly asking if anyone has experience with this, and how they *developed* a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you don't have to check the receipt, but then you are vulnerable to users faking a purchase in various ways.

The green lines are all marked as optional according to the diagram. So only steps 1-5 are truly required, and none of those need your own server.

Comment: thanks, I am actually implementing google play in app purchasing, already. Its instructions come with a variety of anti-fake purchase techniques, would google's licensing regime work on something downloaded from amazon (but with the same package name?), just wondering if you have any experience with this really

Comment: Sorry, no clue on that one.